# How do I force a query to return just one record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm receiving the following error:

> 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, ...

Here's my query:

```
let getLinkTopicsSql = "SELECT       Topic.Id, 
                                     Topic.Name, 
                                     isnull( (select 1 from FeaturedTopic where TopicId = Topic.Id),0) as IsFeatured 

                        FROM         Topic
                        INNER JOIN   LinkTopic
                                        ON   LinkTopic.TopicId = Topic.Id
                        INNER JOIN   Link
                                        ON   LinkTopic.LinkId =  Link.Id
                        WHERE        Link.Id = @LinkId"
```

I tried:

```
SELECT TOP 1
```

Like this:

```
let getLinkTopicsSql = "SELECT TOP 1 Topic.Id, 
                                     Topic.Name, 
                                     isnull( (select 1 from FeaturedTopic where TopicId = Topic.Id),0) as IsFeatured 

                        FROM         Topic
                        INNER JOIN   LinkTopic
                                        ON   LinkTopic.TopicId = Topic.Id
                        INNER JOIN   Link
                                        ON   LinkTopic.LinkId =  Link.Id
                        WHERE        Link.Id = @LinkId"
```

But I'm still receiving the same exception.

I'm not sure how to resolve this...

Comment: It's the subquery in your SELECT clause that needs the TOP 1, not the main query.

Comment: This query `select 1 from FeaturedTopic where TopicId = Topic.Id` is returning more than 1 record. It doesn't know what to do with that result. Try `select TOP 1 1 from FeaturedTopic where TopicId = Topic.Id` or `select DISTINCT 1 from FeaturedTopic where TopicId = Topic.Id`

Comment: That query is **probably non-deterministic** as there is no ORDER BY. Also, turning it into a "normal" join may indicate where the multiplicity can be adjusted..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `exists`:

```
(case when exists (select 1 from FeaturedTopic where TopicId = Topic.Id)
      then 1 else 0
 end) as IsFeatured
```

You could do this with `isnull()`, as in:

```
isnull( (select top (1) 1 from FeaturedTopic where TopicId = Topic.Id), 0) as IsFeatured
```

or without:

```
select coalesce(max(1), 0) from FeaturedTopic where TopicId = Topic.Id) as IsFeatured
```

but I think that `exists` is the clearest form.